# Imprimir todas las palabras coincidentes

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero imprimir por pantalla todas las palabras que coincidan con mi variable (**a**) dentro de un TXT.

```
a = "FFN"
```

Tengo el siguiente código pero lo único que hace es imprimir todas las líneas del archivo:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    a = "FFN"
    for line in f:
        for a in line.split():
            print(a)
```

Contenido de **archivo.txt**:

```
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646817 P1k200 SYNFP4 STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646819 P1k2952 STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646818 SYNFP4
```

Lo que obtengo al ejecutar el código es lo siguiente:

```
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646817
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646819
STX01QFDQIN000SYNQLFNSYNFFN1646818
```

Lo que quiero conseguir es el numero que sigue a mi variable **a**, tal que así:

```
1646817
1646819
1646818
```

Gracias de antemano.

**EDIT**

Suprimiendo la línea del split, he conseguido que solamente me imprima las líneas en las que se encuentra el contenido de mi variable:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
a = 'FFN'
for line in f:
    if a in line:
        print (a)
```

Salida:

```
FFN
FFN
```

Comment: has probado a imprimir la lista desde un elemento hasta el final , que son los numeros que buscas.

Comment: @RoyalUp no lo he conseguido, ya que la string del txt es una sola línea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo tienes que extraer los últimos seis caracteres de cada nombre, usando *rebanado*:

```
with open(r"archivo.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for a in line.split():
            numero = a[-6:]
            print(numero)
```

produce:

```
646817
646819
646818
```

Comment: esto está bien, pero el txt contiene mas datos, no solo las líneas que finalizan con el numero del FFN

Comment: @andyio. La respuesta se ajusta a la información que entregaste y al ejemplo que diste.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, no había visto tu respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: podría ponerse un `if "FFN" in a`... y luego imprimir.